# Python Como asignar la fecha a un Entry(), escogida en un Calendario

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, entrada, class, calendar

Deseo Asignar a un Entry(), la fecha escogida en un calendario. Ya obtengo la fecha del calendario, pero no se exactamente como debo Asignarla, ya que están en módulos diferentes e Intentado Instanciar el método que esta en principalV2.py que es: def FechaCalendario(self, fechaCal): el cual se encargaría de asignar la fecha en el Entry(), correspondiente (fechaEntry ) pero al tratar de instancial el metodo FechaCalendario, me arroja error : NameError: name 'principalV2' is not defined

Adiciono el código:

```
principal.py
from tkinter import *                                                
import re # 
from principalV1 import *


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200+50+50")
    app=principalV1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

```
principalV1.py
from tkinter import * 
from principalV2 import *

# POO en Ventanas Varias.  
class principalV1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("Ventan principal")
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame, text="Crea Nueva Ventana", width=25, bg="cyan", 
        command = self.new_window)
        self.button1.pack() 
        self.frame.pack()

        self.etiqueta = Label(self.frame, text="Ejemplo de una Etiqueta ")
        self.etiqueta.pack()

        self.unEntry = Entry().pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = principalV2(self.newWindow)
```

```
principalV2.py
from tkinter import * 
from miCalendario1 import *

class principalV2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("Nueva Ventana")
        self.master.geometry("400x300+300+50")
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        self.frame.config(height=50, bg="lightgreen", relief="groove" )

        # etiqueta ingrese la fecha validando cada tecla que digite el usuario -------------------------
        self.fectiqueta = Label(self.frame, text="Fecha DD/MM/AAAA",bg="lightgreen").place(x=5,y=50)
        # entry captura la fecha 
        self.fechaEntry = Entry(self.frame, bg="lightblue", font=('Helvetica', 14), width=10)
        self.fechaEntry.place(x=130,y=50)
        
        # este boton creara una nueva  para el calendario unicamente
        self.botCal = Button(self.frame, text="[Cal]", command=self.new_window).place(x=250,y=50)
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # etiqueta ingrese la fecha
        self.numtiqueta = Label(self.frame, text="Ing. 7 Numero",bg="lightgreen").place(x=5,y=90)
        
        # solo numeros
        self.numerosEntry = Entry(self.frame, bg="lightblue", font=('Helvetica', 14), width=10)
        self.numerosEntry.place(x=130,y=90)
        

        # boton salir
        self.quitbutton = Button(self.frame, text="Salir", width=25, bg="orange",
         command = self.close_window).place(x=100, y=250) 
    
        ### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # este metodo asignaria la fecha del calendario al Entry de fecha (fechaEntry)
    def FechaCalendario(self, fechaCal):
        self.fechaCal=fechaCal
        print("Esta es la fecha escogida en el Calendario")
        print(self.fechaCal)
    

    def close_window(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = miCalendario1(self.newWindow)
```

```
miCalendario1.py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial
from datetime import date, datetime
import calendar
from principalV2 import *


class miCalendario1:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("Calendario")
        self.master.geometry("230x200+650+50")
        self.master.config(bg="lavender")
        self.master.resizable(0,0)
        # obtengo la fecha actual
        today = date.today()
        m=today.month # tipo numerico (1,2,3,,,12) obt el mes actual, para el combobox (1,2,3)
        a=today.year # tipo numerico,(2019,2020,2021) obt el año actual, para el combobox ()

        # creo combox para los meses
        lMes=("Enero","febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiebre","Octubre",
              "Noviembre","Diciembre")
        self.cmbMes=ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=lMes, width=10, state="readonly",
                                  font=("arial",10,"bold"))
        self.cmbMes.place(x=10,y=5)
        self.cmbMes.current(m-1) # defaul el mes actual en el combobox, current da el index 0,1,2,3,4
        
        # lleno la lista con los años para el combobox de los años
        lAno=[] # este arreglo recibira, el rango de años habilitados
        for c in range(1900,2099):
            lAno.append(c) # corgo la lista con el rango de años desde a
        #print(lAno)    

        # creo los titulos
        lbl2=Label(self.master,text="Año :", bg="lavender", font=("arial",10,"bold")).place(x=110,y=5)
        # creo combobox para los años
        self.cmbAno=ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=lAno, state="readonly",
                                 font=("arial",10,"bold"), width=5)
        self.cmbAno.place(x=155,y=5)
        self.cmbAno.set(a) # hago como opc, predefinida en año actual
        
        # creo la caja de texto para mostrar el calendario
        self.txt=Text(self.master, width=24, height=8,bg="lightblue", bd=3, padx=5)
        self.txt.place(x=10,y=30)
        
        # llamo la funcion para que muestre x primera vez todo actualizado                                              
        self.MostrarCalendario(self.cmbMes,self.cmbAno,self.txt)
                                                    
        #creao el botton para mostrar el calendario
        btn=Button(self.master,text="Actualice",bg="skyblue", font=("arial",9,"bold"), 
                command=lambda: self.MostrarCalendario(self.cmbMes,self.cmbAno,self.txt))
        btn.place(x=12,y=168)
        
        btnD=Button(self.master,text="Selec Dia",bg="skyblue", font=("arial",9,"bold"), 
                command=lambda: self.DiaSelecionado(self.cmbMes,self.cmbAno,self.txt))
        btnD.place(x=150,y=168)
        
    
    # la funcion q muestra el calendario
    def MostrarCalendario(self, mBox, aBox,txt):
        self.mBox=mBox
        self.aBox=aBox
        self.txt=txt

        self.mesBox=self.mBox.current()+1
        self.anoBox=int(self.aBox.get()) # viene tipo txt, paso a numerico, hay controlar esto
    
        
        self.txt.config(state=NORMAL)
        cal=calendar.month(self.anoBox,self.mesBox)
        self.txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.txt.insert(INSERT, cal)
        self.txt.config(state=DISABLED)

    def DiaSelecionado(self, mBox, aBox,txt):
        try:
            if self.txt.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST).isdigit() and len(self.txt.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)) <=2:
                print( "Texto Seleccionado: '%s'" % self.txt.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST) )
                rDia=self.txt.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
                rMes=str(self.mBox.current()+1)
                rAno=self.aBox.get()
                xFecha=rDia+"/"+rMes+"/"+rAno
                self.rFecha=xFecha
                print(self.rFecha)
                # llamo al metodo  para asignar la fecha escogida en el calendario
                xf=principalV2.FechaCalendario(self.rFecha) 
                # la instancia da esto: NameError: name 'principalV2' is not defined

        except TclError:
            print( "Seleccione el dia" )
```

[image: Modulos ejemplo-asignar fecha escogida del Calendario en Entry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuvo interesante!

### En `principalV2.py`

Al momento de crear tu objeto `miCalendario1`, le pasamos una referencia al objeto `principalV2`:

```
def new_window(self):
    self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = miCalendario1(self.newWindow, self)
```

### En `miCalendario.py`

Ahora que recibimos el objeto padre, hay que guardarlo como un atributo para usarlo más tarde...

```
class miCalendario1:
    def __init__(self,master, padre):
        self.padre = padre
```

Y acá es donde lo usaremos, en la función `DiaSeleccionado`, toca reemplazar la línea que te daba error por la siguiente:

```
def DiaSelecionado(self, mBox, aBox,txt):
    # - - - código - - -
    self.padre.fechaEntry.delete(0, "end")
    self.padre.fechaEntry.insert(0, self.rFecha)
```

Lo que haces es hacer uso de la referencia a tu objeto padre para acceder al `Entry` que tiene, donde debe ir la fecha, y desde ahí modificar su contenido. Nada más!

Comment: Buenas noches a todos.
**DannyTalent**, Excelente tu repuesta, muchísimas gracias
Aplique las instrucciones y **EUREKA**, todo funcionó perfectamente
Lo que mas me ha impresionado es lo sencillo de la solución, pero sin
el **conocimiento** imposible hallarla.
Fueron semanas completas tratando de lograrlo y nada :(
Estoy seguro que este ejercicio será muy útil para muchos principiantes y autodidactas.
Así que de nuevo mil gracias Danny por tu gran ayuda.